# Gain names of the column based on comparision between tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, excel

My goal is to retrieve a result of the name of column based on similiar column from table Product_A and Product_B.

It doesn't matter if I gain the result in excel, notepad or table from sql server. The most important is to retrieve the result.

I don't know how to retrieve the result based on calculation with low usage of manual work?

Some criteria you need to take account to:

- The column must have the same datatype and name to be similiar
- I'm not interrested in retrieving the data from the column
- The table is created in a basic level. In reality, the table use 200 column.

The table is in SQL server 2008 R2

```
TABLE Product_A
(
   ProductID INT,
   ProductName VARCHAR(100),
   Rate MONEY,
   Action INT,
   MapINT,
) 


TABLE Product_B
(
   ProductID INT,
   Count INT,
   ProductName VARCHAR(100),
   Rate MONEY
) 



Requested result

       ProductID INT,
       ProductName VARCHAR(100),
       Rate MONEY,
```

Comment: can you post some sample data and your expected result?  Do you want the products from both tables?  which rate do you want if the rates are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will compare two tables and return only same-named columns of same datatype. If you need to find all matches accross database, comment out `t1.name =` condition.

```
select 
      t1.name TableName, 
      c1.name ColumnName,
      types.name,
      c1.max_length,
      c1.precision,
      c1.scale
 from sys.columns c1
inner join sys.columns c2
   -- Condition to join columns - same name, type, length, precision and scale
   on c1.name = c2.name
  and c1.system_type_id = c2.system_type_id
  and c1.max_length = c2.max_length
  and c1.precision = c2.precision
  and c1.scale = c2.scale
   -- Exclude template table
  and c1.object_id <> c2.object_id
inner join sys.tables t1
   on c1.object_id = t1.object_id
inner join sys.types
   on c1.system_type_id = types.system_type_id
inner join sys.tables t2
   on c2.object_id = t2.object_id
where t2.name = 'Product_B'
   -- remove if you want to search for matches in all tables 
  and t1.name = 'Product_A'
```

Check the documentation on [sys.columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) and [sys.tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are not very clear but you might be referring to a UNION so you can get data from both tables which will give you the product information from each table in separate rows:

```
SELECT ProductId, ProductName, Rate
FROM Product_A
UNION 
SELECT ProductId, ProductName, Rate
FROM Product_B
```

If you could edit your OP and post some sample data and your expected result then the query could be clarified.

If you know which table you want the data from Table A or B, then you could do a JOIN on the ProductName, but you need to decide which Rate and Product Id you want:

```
SELECT a.ProductId
    , a.ProductName
    , a.Rate
FROM Product_A a
JOIN Product_B b
    ON a.ProductName = b.ProductName
```